# We are roaming birds, ready to fly away!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> We are roaming birds, ready to fly away!
>
> We head to the South, and we stash things away
> We head to the West, and we catch the sunray
> We head to the East, for a temporary stay
>
> We head to the North -- what do we do today?

---

<sup>*This is actually my first ever riddle, thanks Deusovi for the help and feedback!*</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are roaming birds, ready to fly away!

> **Aves** - birds, and possibly *ave* meaning "be well" or "farewell" - on your way.

We head to the South, and we stash things away

> **S**ave - to store for the future.

We head to the West, and we catch the sunray

> **W**ave - a sunray can be described as a wave.

We head to the East, for a temporary stay

> **E**ave/s - birds may nest under these - where they stay before migrating.  (Winging this one.)

We head to the North -- what do we do today?

> **N**ave - you go to a church to pray.

Comment: This is correct, well done! :D rot13(Jnf guvaxvat bs fnirf, jnirf, rnirf, anirf; ohg jvgubhg f ner nyfb svar. Gur jnirf pna or uvagrq sbe fhaenl ng gur frn gbb, naq lrnu vg jnf uneq gb trg n cebcre yvar sbe gur rnirf, ohg gur pheerag bar zvtug or orggre guna gur cerivbhf qensg "..., naq tb sbe n ynl.")